# Joomla User Menu Access Level Open Source Component - Help Pl

Tags: php, joomla, jcomponent

I have users in my joomla site.
I have set of menu and they are as follows:

Public: Home|AboutUs|Testimonials|Contact Us (4 Menus)

Registered: Home|AboutUs|ProjectAssigned|List of Projects|Testimonials|Contact Us(6 Menus)

So if user1 login - he will get access to the above six menus(Registered)

Now is it possible to have another two menus(6+2) for user2 so that user1 wont have access to all the eight menu??

In other words, registered users after login - will have access to different menus.

User 1 -> Home|AboutUs|ProjectAssigned|List of Projects|Testimonials|Contact Us

User 2 -> Home|AboutUs|ProjectAssigned|List of Projects|Project1|Project2|Testimonials|Contact Us

User 3 -> Home|AboutUs|ProjectAssigned|List of Projects|Project3|Contact Us

Any open-source component available or is it available by default. I am using Joomla Version 1.5.22.

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This extensions may useful to you;

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/frontend-access-control/6874

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/frontend-access-control/5986

Comment: the above said first link dnt open. the second link is not open source.. Could u suggest why??

Comment: try this                                     http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/frontend-access-control/6874

Comment: I think it is the exact you required ? Have you got the link now ?

Comment: Its not open source. Trail version only available.. Could you pl advice. Pl suggest some open source pl

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/9040  .. Itz non-commercial try it out.